# How to install a pod from the repository with .podspec located in a directory?

Tags: git, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to install a **Pod** from the **git repository** with a branch.

Something like this:

```
pod 'ThePod', :git => 'https://gitlab.kz/company/mobile/ios-app.git', :branch => 'feature-branch'
```

✅ There is no problem if a **.podspec** file is located in the root of the repository.

⚠️ The problem is, that **.podspec** file is located inside the **/src** directory.

So, when I run `pod install`, of course I get

> [!] Unable to find a specification for 'ThePod'.

which is obvious.

Is there any chance to specify the path to a **.podspec** file while using the **:git =>** configuration?

Comment: Maybe with `:podspec => URLPathOfThePodSpec` instead of `:git`?

Comment: @Larme I can link to .podspec raw value which is located in the remote git branch. But, It doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have the same error then? A different one?

Comment: @Larme The different one that says cannot format the contents of URL (URL to podspec). Do you have a working example of how you use `:podspec =>` configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. When I ran into this problem, I moved the .podspec files to the repo root.